# javascript/jquery: hide and uncheck, checked option/options

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, unchecked

The following code gets all the values from the checked checkboxes and store them in an array:

```
function SaveIt(id)
{
 var arrayCheckedCDs = $('input:checkbox[name="checkCD[]"]:checked').map(function () {        
    return this.value;
}).get();
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<form>
    <table id="cdsTable">  
    <tbody>
    <tr>

    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Artist</td>
    <td>Album</td>
    <td>Select</td>
    </tr> 

    <tr id="cd1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Jeff Buckley</td>
    <td>Grace</td>    
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1|Buckley|Grace" name="checkCD[]" id="checkCD1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="cd2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>U2</td>
    <td>Zooropa</td>    
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2|U2|Zooropa" name="checkCD[]" id="checkCD2"></td>
    </tr>
     .
     .                                          
    </tbody></table>

<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:SaveIt(id); return false;"value="submit">
<!-- the id in SaveIt(id) is 1 or 2 or ... I get it from my php script-->
</form>
```

After storing the values in arrayCheckedCDs I need to hide the selected rows and uncheck the selected checks.

The hiding is easy:

```
$('#cdsTable #cd'+id+'').hide();
```

But I don't have a clue on how to uncheck the selected checkboxes because the following is not working:

```
$('checkCD'+id+'').attr('checked', false);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$('#checkCD'+id+'').prop('checked', false);`

Comment: `$('input:checkbox[name="checkCD[]"]:checked').prop('checked', false);`